# Trouble with a MySQL GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to build an SQL query that should spit out all of the users activities, not summed or anything, just a full list of each activities performed.

The problem I am having is, I can't seem to get the GROUP BY working so that each user's activities are printed out.

SQLFiddle = http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5dce6/2

Eventually, I will build this JSON object:

```
users: [{
    userid: '1', 
    name: 'John',
    activities: [{
       activity_typeid: 6431,
       time: "2013-01-01 00:00:00",
       activity_weight: 20
      }, {
       activity_typeid: 6431,
       time: "2013-01-01 00:00:00",
       activity_weight: 20
    }]
}, {
    userid: '2', 
    name: Peter',
    activities: [{
       activity_typeid: 6431,
       time: "2013-01-01 00:00:00",
       activity_weight: 20
      }
    }]
}]
```

SQL :

```
SELECT activity_typeid, userid, time, activity_weight, activityname
FROM activity_entries
WHERE competitionid = '52a99783c5d6f'
```

Comment: `GROUP BY` is for combining multiple rows into one row. If you want to get all the user's activities, you don't need it. Just loop through the results, and add each row as an object in the array.

Comment: SQL can't create JSON directly. You need to use logic in the application program to create nested arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT activity_typeid, userid, time, activity_weight, activityname
FROM activity_entries
WHERE competitionid = '52a99783c5d6f' AND userid = someuserid
```

Comment: So I tried that - but it does not list all the activities performed by a user - see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5dce6/3

Comment: Are you aware that the invalid use of the `group by` operator will return random data in MySQL: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Comment: then you need to change "WHERE competitionid = '52a99783c5d6f'" to "WHERE userid = someuser" or just add "WHERE competitionid = compid AND userid = someuser" and lose group by

Comment: The JSON object in his example has multiple users, so you don't need `userid = someuserid` in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need `GROUP BY` in this case. `ORDER BY` is still makes sense. For example :

```
SELECT activity_typeid, userid, time, activity_weight, activityname
FROM activity_entries
WHERE competitionid = '52a99783c5d6f'
ORDER BY userid
```

Then you can loop through query result. If current data has different `userid` from previous data, create new `user` object, else simply add new `activity` to existing `user` object's `activities`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT userid, username, 
       group_concat(concat_ws(',', activity_typeid, time, activity_weight) separator '; ') as activities
FROM activity_entries
WHERE competitionid = '52a99783c5d6f'
GROUP BY userid;
```

This puts the activities in a string, each separated by a semicolon.  The individual components are then separated by commas.